# Generic wrapper behaving in the same way as wrapped type

Tags: c++, constructor, wrapper

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

template <typename Wrapped>
class Wrapper
{
public:
    template <typename... Args>
    Wrapper(Args&&... args)
    : wrapped(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {
    }

private:
    Wrapped wrapped;
};

Wrapper<std::vector<int>> intended()
{
    std::vector<int>::allocator_type allocator;

    return { { 1, 2, 3 }, allocator }; // doesn't compile
}

Wrapper<std::vector<int>> unintended()
{
    return 123; // calls 'explicit vector(size_type count)'
}
```

What should one do to make such a `Wrapper` almost invisible? For instance - returning `std::vector<int>` doesn't allow such function to compile:

```
std::vector<int> get_vector()
{
    return 123; // doesn't compile
}
```

Comment: `explicit` constructor can be called only by invoking it, e.g. `return std::vector<int>(123);`. In general case, for arbitrary class and type this task is impossible. In some case it is possible by inheriting interface or "Wrapper" should be a "reerence_wapper".

Comment: Your constructor should be conditionaly `explicit`. But not entirely sure with what condition.

Comment: `{ 1, 2, 3 }` has no type. So it cannot be deduced from `T&&` (it can be deduced from `initializer_list` or from `T(&)[N]`.

Answer (score 2):

For `T`'s default constructor, we can determine whether it is implicit by checking whether `const T&` can be initialized with `{}`.

As for whether a type can be implicitly constructible from another type, we can check it by combining `std::is_constructible` and `std::is_convertible`.

So your `Wrapper`'s constructor can be conditionally `explicit` according to the above rules, for example:

```
#include <utility>

template<typename T, typename... Args>
concept implicitly_constructible = 
  requires { [](const T&) {}({std::declval<Args>()...}); };

template<typename Wrapped>
class Wrapper {
 public:
  template<typename T>
    requires std::is_constructible_v<Wrapped, T>
  explicit(!std::is_convertible_v<T, Wrapped>)
  Wrapper(T&& t)
  : wrapped(std::forward<T>(t)) { }

  template<typename... Args>
    requires (sizeof...(Args) != 1) && 
             std::is_constructible_v<Wrapped, Args...>
  explicit(!implicitly_constructible<Wrapped, Args...>)
  Wrapper(Args&&... args)
  : wrapped(std::forward<Args>(args)...) { }
 private:
  Wrapped wrapped;
};
```

It should be noted that for `{1, 2, 3}`, it cannot be deduced from `Args&&`, so you still need to explicitly specify its type such as `std::initializer_list<int>{1, 2, 3}`.

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/MvWsM4Tjf)

Comment: Note that this answer is C++20 (with concept which can be replaced by SFINAE, and [`explicit(expression)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit)).

Comment: Typo: `explicit(!implicitly_constructible<Wrapped, First&&, Rest&&...>)` (missing `Rest`, and reference should be kept, as constructors taking non-const l-value would not be constructible with `U`).

Comment: @Jarod42. I don't quite understand why we need reference, isn't `is_constructible/is_convertible` already using `std::declval<Args>()`?

Comment: My mistake for reference (Due to collapsing, so `First` would be `U&` for my problematic case, so no longer an issue). `std::is_convertible` is the wrong tool, as it handle just one parameter. You might do `implicitly_constructible` as you do for the empty case. you might have `explicit Foo(int); Foo(int, int);` and you consider wrongly second as `explicit` (and reverse case too is problematic).

Comment: "*You might do implicitly_constructible as you do for the empty case.*" I thought the same at the beginning until I found that `vector(initializer_list<T>)` is not `explicit` and it will make `[](const vector<int>&){}({0});` become well-formed. ;-(

Comment: For one parameter, `{}` should be omitted. so `{}`, `1`, `{1, "2"}`, `{1, "2", 3.f}`, ...

Comment: @Jarod42. Yes. I have just updated, but I am not sure if there are any missing cases...

Comment: Last point might be the copy constructor (of `Wrapper`) (for non const l-value) when wrapped type has a constructor which accepts `Wrapper<T>&` (such as template constructor).

Comment: "*when wrapped type has a constructor which accepts Wrapper<T>&*". That's imagination. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

an additional ctor might help...

```
template<class Wrapped>
class Wrapper
{
public:
    template <typename... Args>
    explicit Wrapper(Args&&... args)
    : wrapped(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {
    }

    template <class T, typename... Args>
    Wrapper(std::initializer_list<T> lst, Args&&... args)
    : wrapped(std::move(lst), std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {
    }
private:
    Wrapped wrapped;
};
```