# A way to check if is_explicitly_constructible

Tags: c++, type-traits, explicit

I am looking for a way to implement such a trait:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
struct is_explicitly_constructible
{
    static inline constexpr bool value = // implementation
};
```

Potential usage:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo(void*, void*) {}
    explicit Foo(int, int) {}
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << is_explicitly_constructible<Foo, void*, void*>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << is_explicitly_constructible<Foo, int, int>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Potential output:

```
false
true
```

C++17 required.

Comment: That [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69706433/2684539) provides a `implicitly_constructible` concept.

Comment: You're asking for a composite "explicitly constructible and not implicitly constructible" trait, which is unusual. I can't think of a practical use-case for it. Probably "implicitly constructible" trait would make more sense.

Comment: your notion of `explicitly_constrctible` isnt quite clear, because a constructor that can be called implicitly can also be called explicitly. Perhaps `is_only_explicitly_constructible`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, @463035818_is_not_a_number: Once you have one, it is just mixing the traits, `is_constuctible && !implicitly_constructible == is_only_explicitly_constructible` (and `is_constuctible && !is_only_explicitly_constructible == implicitly_constructible`).

Comment: @Jarod42 exactly, but for `is_explicitly_constructible` imho OPs expected output would be rather confusing

Comment: I basically meant checking if given constructor has the `explict` keyword.

Comment: The opposite solution will come in handy as well - is_implicitly_constructible - meaning that a given type has no explicit keyword in constructors declaration. C++17 required.

Comment: Is the traits from link good enough? (Possible pitfall with `std::initializer_list`).

Comment: @Jarod42 Unfortunately it utilizes a concept which is a C++20 feature. My compiler is limited to C++17 and olders.

Comment: `std::void_t` or similar can turn implementation of that concept in regular traits.

Answer (score 2):

If one does not have access to C++20 lambdas inside `decltype`, the ordinary approach with `void_t<decltype(expr)>` with `expr` `T={args...}` won't work because it is a statement, not an expression. But I think we can leverage the fact that function calls only allow implicit conversion and calls are considered expressions.

Meaning that expression is valid if and only if

`std::declval<void (*)(T)>()({std::declval<Args>()...})`

is valid. It is a call to `void (T)` function with `Args...` arguments suitable for unevaluated contexts.

It is the same trick as the one used for [std::is_convertible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible) except it supports multiple arguments.

#### C++14 solution

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename T, typename, typename... Args>
struct is_implicitly_constructible_impl : std::false_type {};

template <typename T, typename... Args>
struct is_implicitly_constructible_impl<
    T,
    decltype(void(std::declval<void (*)(T)>()(
        {std::declval<Args>()...}))),
    Args...> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T, typename... Args>
using is_implicitly_constructible =
    is_implicitly_constructible_impl<T, void, Args...>;

template <typename T, typename... Args>
constexpr auto is_implicitly_constructible_v =
    is_implicitly_constructible<T, Args...>::value;

template <typename T, typename... Args>
constexpr auto is_only_explicit_constructible_v =
    std::is_constructible_v<T, Args...> &&
    !is_implicitly_constructible_v<T, Args...>;
```

```
struct ExplicitFoo {
    explicit ExplicitFoo(int, float) {}
};

struct ImplicitFoo {
    ImplicitFoo(int, float) {}
};

int main() {
    ImplicitFoo i = {1, 1.0f};
    // ExplicitFoo e = {1, 1.0f};  // ERROR, ctor is explicit
    
    // == bool on purpose for better clarity.
    // std::is_constructible considers explicit ctors
    static_assert(std::is_constructible_v<ImplicitFoo, int, float> == true, "");
    static_assert(std::is_constructible_v<ExplicitFoo, int, float> == true, "");

    static_assert(
        is_only_explicit_constructible_v<ImplicitFoo, int, float> == false, "");
    static_assert(
        is_only_explicit_constructible_v<ExplicitFoo, int, float> == true, "");
}
```

As was pointed in the comments, the desired result can be achieved with mixing the traits.

Comment: `std::void_t` is a feature of C++17.

Comment: In addition, you also need to consider the case when `T` has an *implicit* `std::initializer_list` constructor.

Comment: @康桓瑋 Ugh, true about `std::void_t`, changed, thanks. Not sure how OP wants to consider this case.