# Creating concept checking if return statement is well-formed

Tags: c++, wrapper, type-traits, c++-concepts

While reading one of questions on stack, I asked myself the question:

> What is the easiest way of creating invisible box wrapping a given type that would allow returning it in the same way as wrapped type?

Which means:

If this code is well-formed:

```
T get()
{
    return <expression>
}
```

Then it should be possible to compile this code as well:

```
Box<T> get()
{
    return <expression>
}
```

Any C++ version allowed. The fewer constructors the better.

I was thinking about something like that:

```
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
concept ReturnWellFormed = requires
{
    []() -> T { return { std::declval<Ts>()... }; };
};

template <typename T>
class Box
{
public:
    template <typename... Ts>
    requires(ReturnWellFormed<T, Ts...>)
    constexpr Box(Ts&&... ts)
    noexcept(std::is_nothrow_constructible_v<T, Ts...>)
    : t(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...)
    {
    }

private:
    T t;
};
```

But it does not work as intended. What are your ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but if I am, don't you just need [`std::is_constructible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible) to check if `Box<T>` is constructible from a `T`?

Comment: You don't have to check `return`. Passing a parameter to a function should be equivalent: `template <typename T> void foo(T);`, then check if `foo<T>({...});` well-formed.

Comment: You probably need two constructors, the other one with `std::initializer_list` as first parameter (check how [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/optional) implements its `in_place` constructors). They also should be conditionally explicit, with something like your concept as a condition.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat is `std::initializer_list` really neccessary? The following code works well: [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9r6nMBWBtlIiDrY8) Shouldn't `Ts...` be interpreted in this case as list as well?

Comment: @vojana Your example works, but I thought your goal is to replicate the construction syntax of the wrapped type exactly. With your approach, `Box<std::vector<int>> box(1,2,3);` will work, but it shouldn't.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Good point. Could you provide some code which should handle all possible construction cases? I believe that my snippet can be enhanced with `explicit(expression)` specifier.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to do that. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69706433/2752075) looks good, but it just needs an `initializer_list` constructor.